# Can't decrypt aes "ValueError: Padding is incorrect."

Tags: python, aes

I'm trying to decrypt some text using aes:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding  import pad, unpad
import base64
enc_text = "u\/jR\/dq99cIt9n5JdeJqA6h1keoUvnotNYgEGUKrcscG2\/ytj3iQPJAhe\/\/OPsBATwJS61\/SItlqxH6rfzgVvo6un1\/ja7nFQS3rkNDRaC8rj+qBtNoeoOCk32E73A8rZAXzBks7hb0aGaN0+GAGMdnSCQHGgXWtolN9zRuemwvYLOHEadTryo577AyInKa35TUOwDub\/1OYl+xo+I+auZL4suMNcNNTYE9lhKFU0iY=".encode("utf-8")
key = "3e60a9e7ba37f66060ca7597d5fbc1bc".encode("utf-8")
iv = "www.elahmad.com/".encode('utf-8')
enc_text1=pad(enc_text,16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
dec = cipher.decrypt(enc_text1)
dec=unpad(dec,16)
print(dec)
```

But i get "ValueError: Padding is incorrect."

The key and iv are correct, and you can check using the following tool:
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

I looked at similar questions, but nothing helped. what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: The encrypted text is also base64 encoded but I see no decoding step.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah this was one of the issues , thanks a lot